# KeyError in Flask Python

Tags: python, api, flask, postman

Hello I'm receiving an error of type KeyError in 'reviews' while trying to GET or do anything with my Pyhton Flask data.

**Here is my app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

businesses = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Pizza Mountaint", 
        "town" : "Madrid", 
        "rating" : 5,
        "revivews" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Wine Lake", 
        "town" : "London", 
        "rating" : 4,
        "revivews" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Burger Town", 
        "town" : "Paris", 
        "rating" : 1,
        "revivews" : []
    },
]

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses", methods=["GET"])
def show_all_businesses():
    return make_response(jsonify( businesses))

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>", methods=["GET"])
def show_one_business(id):
    data_to_return = [ business for business in businesses if business["id"] == id ]
    return make_response( jsonify( data_to_return[0]), 200)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses", methods=["POST"])
def add_business():
    next_id = businesses[-1]["id"] + 1
    new_business = {
        "id" : next_id,
        "name" : request.form["name"],
        "town" : request.form["town"],
        "rating" : request.form["rating"],
        "reviews" : []
    }

    businesses.append(new_business)
    return make_response( jsonify( new_business), 201)


@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>", methods=["PUT"])
def edit_business(id):
    for business in businesses:
        if business["id"] == id:
            business["name"] = request.form["name"]
            business["town"] = request.form["town"]
            business["rating"] = request.form["rating"]
            break
    return make_response( jsonify( business), 200)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_business(id):
    for business in businesses:
        if business["id"] == id:
            businesses.remove(business)
            break
    return make_response( jsonify ( {} ), 200)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>/reviews", methods=["GET"])
def fetch_all_reviews(id):
    for business in businesses:
        if business["id"] == id:
            break
    return make_response( jsonify( business["reviews"]), 200)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>/reviews", methods=["POST"])
def add_new_review(id):
    for business in businesses:
        if business["id"] == id:
            if len(business ["reviews"]) == 0:
                new_review_id = 1
            else:
                new_review_id = business["reviews"][-1]["id"] + 1
            new_review = {
                "id" : new_review_id,
                "username" : request.form["username"],
                "comment" : request.form["comment"],
                "stars" : request.form["stars"]
            }
            business["reviews"].append(new_review)
            break
    return make_response (jsonify(new_review), 201)

@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<int:id>/reviews/<int:review_id>", methods=["GET"])
def fetch_one_review(id, review_id):
    for business in businesses:
        if business["id"] == id:
            for review in business["reviews"]:
                if review["id"] == review_id:
                    break
            break
        return make_response( jsonify ( review ), 200)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Here is the code and the error looks like this: **Desktop\FSSD\app.py", line 76, in fetch_all_reviews
return make_response( jsonify( business["reviews"]), 200)
KeyError: 'reviews'**

This happens when I try to access the data using localhost on the browser or just GET data in postman on that address.

The http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/businesses/ works by displaying results however when trying to hit http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/businesses/1/reviews I receive the KeyError in ( jsonify( business["reviews"]), 200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `businesses` list

```
businesses = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Pizza Mountaint", 
        "town" : "Madrid", 
        "rating" : 5,
        "revivews" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Wine Lake", 
        "town" : "London", 
        "rating" : 4,
        "revivews" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Burger Town", 
        "town" : "Paris", 
        "rating" : 1,
        "revivews" : []
    },
]
```

`revivews` in each dict should be `reviews`

Then `business["reviews"]` will work fine